# MDS import data queue

Tags: master-data-services

I am following this guidance: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/3806/sql-server-master-data-services-importing-data/

The instructions say after we load data into the staging tables, we go into the MDS integration screen and select "START BATCHES".

Is this a manual override to begin the process? or how do I know how to automatically queue up a batch to begin?

Thanks!

Comment: I found this tutorial - [Importing Data Into Master Data Services 2012](https://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2013/2/16/importing-data-into-master-data-services-2012-part-1.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Alternative way to run the staging process

After you load the staging table with required data.. call/execute the **Staging UDP**.
Basically, Staging UDPs are different Stored Procedures for every entity in the MDS database (automatically created by MDS) that follow the naming convention:

```
stg.udp_<EntityName>_Leaf
```

You have to provide it values for some parameters. Here is a sample code of how to call these.

```
USE [MDS_DATABASE_NAME]  
GO

EXEC [stg].[udp_entityname_Leaf]
      @VersionName = N'VERSION_1',
      @LogFlag = 1,
      @BatchTag = N'batch1'
      @UserName=N’domain\user’

GO
```

For more details look at:
[Staging Stored Procedure (Master Data Services)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/master-data-services/staging-stored-procedure-master-data-services?view=sql-server-2016).
Do remember that the `@BatchTag` value has to match the value that you initially populated in the Staging table.

### Automating the Staging process

The simplest way for you to do that would be to schedule a job in SQL Agent which would execute something like the code above to call the staging UDP.
Please note that you would need to get creative about figuring out how the Job will know the correct Batch Tag.

That said, a lot of developers just create a single SSIS Package which does the Loading of data in the Staging table (as step 1) and then Executes the Staging UDP (as the final step).
This SSIS package is then executed through a scheduled SQL Agent job.

Comment: Answer Marked and +1 for such an awesome answer.  question.  the DOMAIN\USERNAME....is that administrative? or authentication?  is the username meant to be the login to execute? or just data to say who did it?  Thanks!

Comment: Username is just for Who did it. Does not need to have admin rights. But make sure it has at least Modify access inside MDS (when you go to the Security page of the MDS Web UI) to the entity that is being loaded/staged.
If this is inside an enterprise then its usual to have a System ID (that may also be the MDS Admin) to be used here. Remember again that this ID should have been provided access inside MDS->Security.